# Is the following expression correct in MIPS

Tags: mips

I'm doing an assignment and I'm just wondering if I did this expression right. The expression is `f = -g - A[4]`

f is `$s0`, g is `$s1`, and the base address for A is `$s6`

```
subu $t1, $zero, $s1 // negate g
addi $t2, $zero, 4   // index for A
add  $t3, $t2, $s6   // put A[4] in $t3
subu $s0, $t1, $t3   // f = -g -A[4]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not correct.

First, the result depends on the type of `A`, because you need to add different values to get the offset.

Moreover you don't really need a separate `add` for calculating offset of a constant array element. You can use `addi $t3, $s6, 4` if `A` is a byte-array, or `addi $t3, $s6, 16` if it's a word-array. Of course you'll need that when the index is big or when it's a variable

However you also need to load the value from that calculated address

```
lw $t4, 0($t3)
```

because adding addresses doesn't give you what's stored in that address